# Почему не работает MouseWheelEvent в ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть такая xaml разметка:

```
    <ContentControl Content="Какой-то текст"
                    MouseWheel="ContentControl_MouseWheel">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
```

Мне нужно отловить событие прокрутки колесика мыши, при нахождении курсора в области `ContentControl`. Однако это событие отрабатывает если курсор находится над элементом `TextBlock`. В пустых областях `ContentControl'a` событие не вызывается.

Как поймать событие прокрутки колесика мыши и при этом иметь возможность централизовать контент по центру `ContentControl'a`?

Технологический стек: C#, WPF, .Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы контрол обрабатывал события мыши, он должен иметь какую-нибудь кисть фона, хотябы прозрачную, установите ее, например, так:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    ...
```

или, возможно правильнее:

```
<ContentControl ... Background="Transparent">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}">
                ...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Это помогло. Не знал про условие с кистью фона.

Comment: Теперь знаете, пожалуйста :)